# React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "posts" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
Posts.js

import React from 'react'
import Post from './Post/Post'
import UseStyles from "./style"
import {useSelector} from "react-redux"
function posts() {
    const classes= UseStyles()
    const Posts=useSelector((state)=>state.Posts)       //This state refers the to the whole redux store and in this state.Post, post is coming form the Reducers/index.js
    console.log(Posts)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>POSTS</h1>
            <Post/>
            <Post/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default posts

index.js

import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import Posts from "./Posts";
export default combineReducers({ Posts })
```

src\Components\Posts\Posts.js
Line 7:17:  React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "posts" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

this is the actual error. At first it was state.posts as mentioned in this error then I changed it, still it shows the same error, I also restart my server but nothing new is happend.

Comment: Change it from posts to Posts and see what happens

Comment: Why are you combining the `Posts` component into your reducers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper React components are PascalCased. You should also move the console log into an `useEffect` so it's an intentional side-effect in what's otherwise considered a pure function.

```
...
import useStyles from "./style"
...

function Posts() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.Posts);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(posts);
  }, [posts])'
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>POSTS</h1>
      <Post/>
      <Post/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```